# Validate combobox items

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-2012

I have a combobox on my window form.  I am using parameterized query to insert the items from the combobox. I want to validate my control. If I do not select any items so message box should be display "Please select the item" or if I select the items so that item which I have selected in the combobox should be insert into my database table . I have tried my codes are below. but I got one error message

> Must declare the scalar variable @ProductCategory.

```
if (comboproductcategory.SelectedIndex < 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please select the item");
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCategory", comboproductcategory.SelectedItem);
}
```

Please guide me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Can you share more code (the whole connection/command initialization, SQL/stored procedure)?

Comment: Ugh, just spent like 5 mins cleaning all this up only to not be able to save it because someone else posted an edit for review. *sigh*

Comment: What is the `SqlDbType` of `ProductCategory`?
Please also post how are you executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code as :

```
  if (comboproductcategory.SelectedIndex < 0)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCategory", DBNull.Value);
        MessageBox.Show("Please select the item");
    }
    else
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCategory", comboproductcategory.SelectedItem);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Beldi Anouar

Comment: If you're going that way, you don't need to add the parameter, just add a return after `MessageBox.Show`.